# trouble when exporting notebook to html on Jupyter with R kernel

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

The following code works fine when writing an ipython notebook equipped with the R kernel. Unfortunately, the export to html fails for the second barplot (both with the embedded option of jupyter and manual use of nbconvert).

```
library(NLP)
library(tm)

# here I used the EBook of Ulysses, by James Joyce, but any text file can fit
# the text is available here: https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/4300/pg4300.txt
book <- readLines("pg4300.txt", encoding="UTF-8")
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(book))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
m <- as.matrix(dtm)

freq <- rowSums(m)
freq.sorted <- sort(freq, decreasing=TRUE)

# first barplot with stop words (ok for both notebook and export)
barplot(freq.sorted[1:50], xlab="Word", ylab="Frequency", las=2)

corpus.sw <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
dtm.sw <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus.sw)
m.sw <- as.matrix(dtm.sw)
freq.sw <- rowSums(m.sw)
freq.sw.sorted <- sort(freq.sw, decreasing=TRUE)

# second barplot without stop words (ok on ipython notebook but fail when exporting)
barplot(freq.sw.sorted[1:50], xlab="Word", ylab="Frequency", las=2)
```

What is really weird, it is that the first barplot is well exported, but not the second one whereas the process is exactly the same (showing the 50 top words).

Here is my configuration:

- macosx 10.11.2 el capitan
- jupyter 4.0.6
- ipython 4.0.1
- R version 3.2.2

Thank you,

Julien

Comment: I can export that, but the second plot has garbled x labels. I think the reason is that the nbconvert does not use iframes for the svg plots, like it is done in the notebook itself.

Comment: This issue is now tracked in https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/290

Answer (score 0):

As this [seems to be caused by how the svg plots are embedded in the html page](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/290), you can probably work around this issue by removing SVG plots from the plotting options:

```
options(jupyter.plot_mimetypes = c("text/plain", "image/png" )) # no more svg...
```